# Prove that if $G$ is a $k$-edge-connected graph, then $G+K_1$ is $(k+1)$ -edge-connected (my proof)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, graph-theory, proof-writing, connectedness

I have a proof that is different from the ones proposed previously and I want to see if my proof works as well. I want to do my proof by contradiction.

First, let $H= G +K_1$ and suppose for the sake of contradiction that it is not $(k+1)$-edge-connected. Let $X$ be a vertex-cut of $H$ where $|X|=k$. Also, let $v$ be the vertex of $K_1$ in $H$.

Case 1: If $v\notin\ X$, then since $v$ is adjacent to all other vertices in G, there is an edge from each vertex in $H-X$ to $v$. Thus, $H-X$ is connected, which is a contradiction.

Case 2: If $v\in\ X$, then $H-X= G- (X-{v})$. However since $G$ is $k$-edge-connected and $|X-v|=k-1$, then $G- (X-{v})$ is still connected because we have not removed enough vertices in order for sufficient edges to be removed to disconnect the graph. This is a contradiction.

Then, $H$ is $(k+1)$-edge-connected.

I was going to do an edge-cut instead but I am not sure how to fix it to make it work that way.

For the first case, if I instead look at this as $X$ is an edge-cut can I say this is the case where no edge in the set is adjacent to $v$ , but then $G-X$ is still connected because of the remaining edges, there is an edge connecting every vertex of $G$ to $v$?

Comment: Can you define $G+K_1$?

Comment: It seems that $G + K_1$ is obtained from $G$ by adding a vertex that is adjacent to all other vertices.

Comment: @VincentPfenninger Yes, sorry, this is what I mean. The vertex in $K_1$ is adjacent to every vertex of $G$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $k$-edge-connected graph does not have to be $k$-connected (e.g. the [Butterfly Graph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ButterflyGraph.html) is 2-edge-connected but not 2-connected (it has a cut vertex)). So you really have to argue with an edge-cut and not a vertex-cut.

Here is how to fix your proof:

First note that since $G$ is $k$-connected the minimum degree of $G$ is at least $k$ and thus $G$ has at least $k+1$ vertices.
Let $H = G + K_1$ and suppose for the sake of contradiction that $H$ is not $(k+1)$-edge-connected. Let $W$ be the vertex set of the copy of $G$ in $H$ and let $v$ be the vertex of $K_1$ in $H$. Further, let $F \subseteq E(H)$ be an edge-cut of $H$ where $|F| = k$. If $F$ contains any of the edges incident to $v$, then $H[W] - F$ is connected since $G$ is $k$-edge-connected. Further, since there are $k+1$ edges to $v$ and we are only removing $k$ edges at least one such edge remains and thus $H-F$ is connected. If $F$ does not contain any of the edges incident to $v$, then $H-F$ is clearly connected, since from every vertex there is a path (of length at most 2) going through $v$ to every other vertex. In either case $H-F$ is connected, thus we have a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, I understand the second case of the set $F$ not having any edges incident to $v$ then $H-F$ is still connected, but I am a bit unclear of the first one where there are some edges in $F$ that are incident to $v$. Are you considering what happens when we remove $F$ from $G$ alone?

Comment: Just for clarity, when you say in the first case "contains any of the edges incident to $v$" you mean this set contains only some of the edges incident to $v$?

Comment: By $H[W]$ I mean the graph induced by the vertex set $W$, that is, in this case, just our copy of $G$ in $H$. Since we are removing some of the edges incident to $v$ which are not a part of the copy of $G$ we are removing at most $k-1$ edges from the copy of $G$ which means that the part of $H$ that was a copy of $G$ (what I call $H[W]$) is still connected (since $G$ is $k$-connected). Now we only have to show that, $H[W]$ is also connected to $v$. But this is immediate, since there are $k+1$ edges from $v$ to $W$ and we are only removing $k$ edges, hence at least one such edge must remain.

Comment: The reason I first show that $G$ has at least $k+1$ vertices is that it then follows that there are at least $k+1$ edges incident to $v$ in $H$ and thus, since we are only removing $k$ edges, one such edge remains. I.e. $F$ cannot contain all the edges incident to $v$, since there are $k+1$ such edges and there are only $k$ edges in $F$.

Comment: Okay, I think I sort of understand and it might just be the notation. So, what you are doing in $H-F=G-....$ ? I think my question is why exactly you are only removing the edges in $F$ from only the copy of G in H, although I do understand the contradiction you are making.

Comment: I am removing all the edges in $F$ from $H$, but then I first look at the part of $H-F$ that was the copy of $G$ (which has vertex set $W$) and show that this part is connected because it is $G-F'$, where $F'$ is the set of edges in $F$ that are in the copy of $G$ in $H$. Then I show that in $H-F$ the vertex $v$ is connected to some vertex in $W$ and thus the whole graph $H-F$ is connected.

Comment: Okay, that makes more sense. So you broke it down into two part. You said in $H-F$ the copy of $G$ in $H$ is still connected because when we remove the edges of $F$ that come from $G$, what happens? I see you mention it is still connected due to $G$ being $k$-edge connected, but so you are saying in this case $F'$ has less than $k$ edges?

Comment: We are considering the case where $F$ contains at least one of the edges incident to $v$, since these edges are added, they are not a part of the copy of $G$, so we are removing at most $|F|-1 = k-1$ edges from the copy of $G$. So $|F'| \leq k-1 <k$.

Comment: Okay, so you are saying if we look at the copy of $G$ in H, then removing only the edges in $F$ that are incident to vertices in G, which has size at most $k-1$  (where the one is from the edge incident to v), then $G$ - these edges is connected still because it is $k$-connected.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Okay, got it. Then, you focused on just the vertex $v$ after stating that the copy of $G$ in $H$ is still connected. Why did you do this? Can't we stop at the fact that $G$ is still connected to arrive at a contradiction?

Comment: To arrive at a contradiction we need to show that $H-F$ is connected. Since $v$ is a vertex of $H-F$ we need to show that it is connected to the other vertices of $H-F$ i.e. to $W$ the vertex set of the copy of $G$ in $H$. A priori it could be that the vertices in $W$ are connected to each other but not to $v$, then $H-F$ would not be connected. We show that this is impossible since there are $k+1$ edges connecting $v$ to $W$ and we are only removing $k$ edges.

Comment: Okay, I see we only have that $G$ Inside $H$ is connected but this doesn’t cover that there is some edge from those in $G$ to $v$. How do we know there are $k+1$ edges? We just know that $G$ is $k$-edge connected.

Comment: We know that $G$ is $k$-edge-connected, thus the minimum degree of $G$ must be at least $k$, because if there was a vertex of degree at most $k-1$, then we could disconnect $G$ by removing the all the edges incident to that vertex, which contradicts the fact that $G$ is $k$-edge-connected. Now we know that $G$ has minimum degree at least $k$ thus every vertex has at least $k$ neighbours. In particular there need to be at least $k+1$ vertices in $G$ (take one vertex and all its neighbours). [continued in the next comment]

Comment: Now in $H$ the vertex $v$ is adjacent to every vertex in $G$. Thus, since there at least $k+1$ vertices in $G$, there are at least $k+1$ edges connecting $G$ to $v$.

Comment: Okay, but how do we know there are at least $k+1$ vertices in $G$?

Comment: I had to split my last comment into two parts, I suspect that you only read the second one.

Comment: Yes, sorry I did only see you’re last comment. Okay, I do see that the minimum degree should be at least $k$ then since that is a theorem. Just how does taking a vertex and all it’s neighbors give us $k+1$ vertices particularly in $G$? Wouldn’t this be the case for $H$?

Comment: Forget about $H$ for the moment. To show that $G$ has at least $k+1$ vertices we only need to talk about $G$. Take any vertex $w$ in $G$. If $w$ has less than $k$ neighbours in $G$, then we have a contradiction to the assumption that $G$ is $k$-edge-connected, because removing all the edges incident to $w$ (which are less than $k$ edges because $w$ has less than $k$ neighbours) results in a disconnected graph. Thus $w$ has at least $k$ neighbours. Now $w$ and its neighbours must be distinct vertices in $G$. Thus there are at least $k+1$ vertices in $G$.

Comment: Okay, I see now that G must have at least $k+1$ vertices so it may be more? Then since $v$ is adjacent to all vertices of $G$, there are at least $k+1$ edges from $v$ to $G$? Then removing only $k$ edges in $H$ is not enough because at least one vertex of $G$ is still connected to $v$.

Comment: Yes, you got it!

Comment: Okay, finally! Sorry for so many questions, but I like to make sure I actually understand the proposed proof and not just take it and go with it. Thank you for all the help!

Comment: No problem. I think it is good that you are taking the matter seriously and want to understand the proof properly.

Comment: Yes, I like to take the time to really understand the proof so I actually learn the method. I did just have one more general question, which I think I already understand by now but, why did you choose to split it up into looking at $G$ in $H$ first and then $v$ in $H$? Wouldn't just saying that since $G$ is $k$-edge-connected give us the $k+1$ vertices $v$ is adjacent to and we would be done (at least in the first case)?

Comment: I split it up into two parts as follows. I first show that, after removing the edges, the part that was $G$ is still connected and that also $v$ is connected to some vertex in $G$. If the part that was $G$ where not connected, then it could be that $v$ is only connected to vertices in one connected component and then the whole graph would not be connected. So we really also have to show that the part that was $G$ is still connected. Splitting the proof up in this way is natural because we have to somehow use the assumption that $G$ is $k$-edge-connected.

Comment: Okay, perfectly clear now. Many thanks!